Perform a silent install using command prompt
How do I perform a silent install with this file after unzipping? No matter what command I write, it opens up a dialog to manually press the Extract button; how can I press the Extract button automatically and go to the next step?

I've tried:
CDM212364_Setup.exe /help

CDM212364_Setup.exe /VERYSILENT /LOG /NORESTART

CDM212364_Setup.exe /Extract




Some .exe installers may support command line switches, however it's not native for those archives, whereas for .msi installers it is, being executed via msiexec. Many developers provide an .msi installer on their site, else it may be worth emailing them.

looks like 7zip will extract the outer installer, which results in another exe file...  I'd try that. You can further extract that to get the driver files out. That might be a start.

Sure thank you. I'll try it out.
